# How can I style the range input to have differnet colors left/right side(only css)

Tags: html, css, reactjs, next.js

This is my tsx right now :

```
"use client";
import { useState } from "react";

export function Slider() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(10);

  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const newValue = parseInt(e.target.value);
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="pass__slider">
        <span>Character Length</span>
        <span>{value}</span>
      </div>
      <div className="pass__slider-container">
        <input
          type="range"
          min={1}
          max={20}
          id="slider"
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is how im trying to style it

```
:root {
  /* Colors */
  --clr-primary-grey-500: hsl(251, 9%, 53%);
  --clr-primary-grey-700: hsl(248, 10%, 15%);
  --clr-primary-grey-800: hsl(248, 15%, 11%);
  --clr-primary-neonGreen-400: hsl(127, 100%, 82%);
  --clr-primary-red-500: hsl(0, 91%, 63%);
  --clr-primary-orange-500: hsl(13, 95%, 66%);
  --clr-primary-yellow-500: hsl(42, 91%, 68%);

  --clr-background-black-700: #14131b;
  --clr-background-black-800: #08070b;

  --clr-neutral-almostWhite-200: hsl(252, 11%, 91%);
}

.pass__slider-container {
  margin-top: 23px;
  width: 100%;
}

input[type="range"] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  background: var(--clr-background-black-800);
  outline: none;
}

input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: var(--clr-neutral-almostWhite-200);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: var(--clr-primary-neonGreen-400);
}
```

I've seen a few solution's asking the same question but didnt manage to make it work.Any suggestions on what I did wrong or what am I missing?

This is the current look of the Slider Component :

[image: Slider Component]

All im trying to do is make the left side of the input (or progress) neonGreen while the rest(right side) remains the same color as it is now.